# Creating a binary variable based on conditions from from two continuous variables in R

Tags: r, if-statement

Consider table A below:

| Age | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 14 |
| 2 | 15 |
| 3 | 15 |
| 3 | 16 |
| 5 | 18 |

I want to create a new binary variable such that:

If age is equal to 1, and score is greater than or equal to 10 **OR** if age is greater than or equal to 2, and score is greater than or equal to 14, then NEWVAR = 1 (anything that does not meet these criteria would be coded as 0).

I tried the following code, but it did not work:

```
A$NEWVAR <- ifelse(A$score >=10 & A$Age == 1 | A$score >=14 & A$Age >= 2, 1,0)
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo in your command (A$score should be A$Score); change this and add some brackets and the command works as expected:

```r
A <- read.table(text = "Age Score
1   7
1   14
2   15
3   15
3   16
5   18", header = TRUE)

A
#>   Age Score
#> 1   1     7
#> 2   1    14
#> 3   2    15
#> 4   3    15
#> 5   3    16
#> 6   5    18

A$NEWVAR <- ifelse((A$Score >= 10 & A$Age == 1) | (A$Score >= 14 & A$Age >= 2), 1,0)
A
#>   Age Score NEWVAR
#> 1   1     7      0
#> 2   1    14      1
#> 3   2    15      1
#> 4   3    15      1
#> 5   3    16      1
#> 6   5    18      1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your response, which works. I think something that I failed to mention was that I had "NAs" for the scores for some of the ages, and these NAs are producing zeroes. I want NAs to be produced if that was the "score" in the original dataset.

Comment: You can nest `ifelse()` statements; try `A$NEWVAR <- ifelse(A$Age == "NA", "NA", ifelse((A$Score >= 10 & A$Age == 1) | (A$Score >= 14 & A$Age >= 2), 1,0))`